# Getting log4j2 to work with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I know there is allot of questions been asked on this but i have been trying to get this to work for few day's and i am not any more forward then when i started.

i have tried to use `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties` and `-Dlog4j.debug` in eclipse vm arguments (under debug & run) and get no output

I have tried to use .properties and .xml but no joy

Tried to put the .xml and .properties files at the root, in the src and in an external folder which i added to my classpath ... still no joy

I think its using another .xml or .properties files in another lib/jar but because i cant get any debug to work i am finding very difficult to track what i am doing wrong here...

any help would be great! below is the code .. only the error message get's printed.

I have download (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) and imported into my app the 
`log4j-api-2.0-beta8.jar
log4j-core-2.0-beta8`

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class CucmServMonitor 
{
 private static final Logger logger  = LogManager.getLogger(CucmServMonitor.class.getName())
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    logger.error("testing ERROR level");
    logger.trace("exiting application");
    System.out.println(logger.getName());   
  }
}
```

the xml file i am using just now log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration status="WARN">
  <appenders>
   <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
   </Console>
  </appenders>
 <loggers>
  <root level="debug">
   <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
  </root>
 </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231773/specifying-a-custom-log4j-properties-file-for-all-of-junit-tests-run-from-eclips

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Manage to figure this one out. The hint was here.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-112.htm

I needed to add a "class folder" of where the log4j2.xml was located and then make sure it was at TOP of the list:

[image: Right click on your project and go to properties]
Right click on your project and go to properties

Then follow the step shown below. After adding the folder make sure its at the top and then click ok
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or... just create a resources directory like src/test/resources and add the log4j.xml file to that dir and then make that directory a source folder.  Then eclipse will automatically copy the file to the the classes dir and there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the log4j.properties file inside the root folder

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, CONSOLE

# Appender writes to console
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

2) Modify the code like this

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
public class CucmServMonitor {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CucmServMonitor.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); 
        logger.error("testing ERROR level");
        logger.trace("exiting application");
        System.out.println(logger.getName());  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. maybe this is the issue i am having but with the jar files I have imported I can only use the following import statements `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`

Answer (score 0):

according to Alexis comment, I setup it, but eclipse still can not find log4j2.xml. finally, I solved it by removing the other jars imported, only keep log4j-api and log4j-core. before I imported all the jars downloaded from the Apache website. hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

According to Alexis comment, I setup it, but eclipse still can not find `log4j2.xml`. finally, I solved it by removing the other jars imported, only keep `log4j-api` and `log4j-core`. before I imported all the jars downloaded from the Apache website.

I solved my project for `log4j->log4j2` version upgrading.